# Python flask POST request

Tags: python, http, flask, post

I develop an app in Python and use flask.
Here is a snippet of code that tries to generate a message by user input and then attach it to my database:

```
@app.route('/MakeMessage',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def MakeMessage():
   if request.method == 'POST':
       user_id = request.form['user_id']
       content = request.form['content']
       paticipants = [request.form['participant1'],request.form['participant2'],request.form['participant3']]
       m = Message(user_id=user_id,content=content,participants=paticipants)
       return redirect('/AddMessage',m = m)

@app.route('/AddMessage',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def AddMessage(m):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      db.session.add(m)
      db.session.commit()
      return 'Your message has been successfully saved'
```

I know something is wrong with the code, but I don't know what.
Any idea?

Comment: what is the error you are facing?

Comment: redirect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'm'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [redirect while passing arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057191/redirect-while-passing-arguments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use `url_for()` in the redirect function to redirect to a route in your application. In addition, you need to put `<m>` in your route for `AddMessage`.

```py
from flask import redirect, url_for, request

@app.route('/MakeMessage',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def MakeMessage():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      ...
      return redirect(url_for('/AddMessage',m=m))

@app.route('/AddMessage/<m>',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def AddMessage(m):
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AddMessage
```

takes a parameter `m`
So in the app.route it should be changed to this

```
@app.route('/AddMessage/<m>')
```

Comment: Could also be expecting it in the body of the post request, in which case the issue may be that `m` should not be a parameter at all and instead should be assigned as `request.data` after verifying the request was a POST.

Comment: That could be the case