# Can you pass additional parameter to return redirect(url_for())? As you can for return render_template()

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I'm trying pass a message similar to return render_template('name.html', msg=msg) in a return redirect(url_for('name'), msg=msg). But it doesn't work.  Is it possible to do?

Thanks,

DL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [redirect while passing arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057191/redirect-while-passing-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got an endpoint like

```python
@app.route("/name")
def name():
   msg = request.args.get("msg")
   return render_template("name.html", msg=msg)
```

you can use

```python
return redirect(url_for("name", msg=msg))
```

in another endpoint to redirect to `/name` and pass `msg` as an argument.

Comment: My endpoint looks similar but like this

@app.route("/name")
def name():
   msg = "Wrong information"
   return render_template("name.html", msg=msg)

this is ok and works.

I tried as you suggest prior to creating this post:
return redirect(url_for("name", msg=msg))

And it doesn't pass that message to the name.html script.  Is it correct to use redirect like this?

Does it matter if it's single quotes or double?

Comment: Single our double quotes do not matter. In your post, you wrote `redirect(url_for('name'), msg=msg)` instead of `redirect(url_for('name', msg=msg))`, have you set the brackets correctly?

Comment: I have set the brackets correctly, and still not passing the message to name.html using redirect(url_for())